# Bootstrap navbar textbox/login panel

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Basically my textbox's aren't the default bootstrap style, it's also out of place and quite messy?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/lsEoy.png < Example

what's the issue, why aren't my textbox's using the bootstrap style

```
 <li class="dropdown pull-right" id="menu1">
         <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#menu1">
           Login<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-leaf"></i>
            <b class="caret"></b>
         </a>
         <div class="dropdown-menu">
           <form style="margin: 0px" accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/sessions" method="post"><div style="margin:0;padding:0;display:inline"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="&#x2713;" /><input name="authenticity_token" type="hidden" value="4L/A2ZMYkhTD3IiNDMTuB/fhPRvyCNGEsaZocUUpw40=" /></div>
             <fieldset class='textbox' style="padding:10px">
               <input style="margin-top: 8px" type="text" placeholder="Username" />
               <input style="margin-top: 8px" type="password" placeholder="Passsword" />
               <input class="btn btn-info" name="commit" type="submit" value="Log In" />
             </fieldset>
           </form>
         </div>
       </li>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not adding the bootstrap class to the input boxes that contains the style for them. You need to do:

```
<input style="margin-top: 8px" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Username" />
<input style="margin-top: 8px" class="form-control" type="password" placeholder="Passsword" />
```

Note the class="form-control" there. That will give it Bootstrap styles.

Comment: Thank you for your help, appreciate the support :).